# Android: Is it possible to pass intent several activities ahead?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

For example: I have 5 activities:

Activity A --> Activity B --> Activity C --> Activity D --> Activity E

Activity A **must** go through Activity B then C then D then E in **sequence**.

I want to pass an intent in Activity A to Activity E **without** passing it through B, C, D.

Is it possible to do that?

My passing intent in Activity A currently:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabAddConList);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent createContactList = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                createContactList.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                createContactList.putExtra("userid", userID);
                startActivity(createContactList);
            }
        });
```

My receiving intent in Activity E currently:

```
 Intent lastIntent = getIntent();
        userid = lastIntent.getStringExtra("userid");
```

**-----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------**

As based on my codes in  this post, I am passing the intent in Activity A to Activity B instead of E, because I want to go to Activity B when I click the button. But how can I go to Activity B without passing the "userid" to Activity B and keep it till it reached Activity E?

Comment: what is your problem ? i mean you are facing any issue.

Comment: @androidnoobdev Hi, my issue is I have trouble passing the intent through all activities B, C, and D. So I am trying to find out if I can pass it straight from A to E instead without passing it through B,C and D.

Comment: @JothanCamos yes you can directly call activity E. it depends upon your app use case. how you pass data or how/when user will see screen.

Comment: I think you can only pass the data from one Intent to the other and so on till you reach Activity E. But an ideal solution would be to store it in persistent data(Shared Preferences) and used when needed. Even simpler would be to store it in the Application subclass(Or any singleton class), if you think shared preference is an overhead.

Comment: @androidnoobdev For my app, the user will have to go through activity A to E in sequence. The user cannot go from Activity A to Activity E straight without passing B,C and D. Can I still pass the intent from A to E when process is still going in sequence like A,B,C,D, E?

Comment: @JothanCamos store userid in preference when you got it. and then access it from wherever you want and then remove it if not required so security even remain.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to have an `Activity` pass an `Intent` to the next `Activity` in the sequence without first receiving that `Intent`. How else to pass it on?

In your case, consider writing the piece of information for `Activity` *E* to `SharedPreferences`. They use key-value pairs for storing data just like intents do, see also this [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

By the way, from a security point of view: at least in some versions of android, the `Intent` used with `startActivity()` is not private to your app. So be careful not to pass sensitive data with `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As long as intent is not clear everything will pass with intent from start to end. Whenever you want to clean intent data you can call

```
getIntent().removeExtra("key");
```

If you want to forward the intent. You can do it by

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(receivedIntent);
```

Comment: Hi, where do I add this line of code? As currently the intent isn't passing through with my current codes

Comment: Please check if you are creating new instance of intent or getting reference of existing intent and passing it alone. Better put call of startActivity for each call with intent how you are passing intent. It will help to understand each call from start to end.

Comment: Do not create new instance like you are doing  - Intent createContactList = new Intent(context, ActivityE.class); Better get existing intent from received intent like this. Intent newIntent = new Intent(receivedIntent);

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to pass value from all activities.

Otherthan this you can use `SharedPreferences` to store value in `Activity A` and fetch that value in `Activity E`. check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for reference.

Other way is static variable, take `public static` variable in A and access it from `Activity E`

in Activity A

```
public static String yourVariable="value";
```

in Activity E access it by using `A.yourVariable`

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> For my app, the user will have to go through activity A to E in
>   sequence. The user cannot go from Activity A to Activity E straight
>   without passing B,C and D. Can I still pass the intent from A to E
>   when process is still going in sequence like A,B,C,D, E?

***your all activity in sequence then you must have to pass value from all activities using intent.***

alternative

use `Preference` to store your value or `static variable`

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use a public static variable (or singleton) to store a value to be read at a later point by another activity.  Usually you don't want to use statics like this, but it might be the easiest thing for you to do.

This is basic application of static variables in Java.  Declare a new class with the state you want to retain:

```
public class State {
    public static String value;
}
```

In Activity A:

```
State.value = "value that you want to read in activity E"
```

In Activity E:

```
String v = State.value;
```

Comment: it can create memory leak issue. don't give temporary solutions.

Comment: If it's just a short string or an integer, that's not really a leak.  A leak is when an object is retained longer than its *expected* lifetime.  Here we fully expect basic string object to live beyond the activity.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you give an example?

Comment: As based on my codes in the post, I am passing the intent to Activity B instead of E, because I want to go to Activity B when I click the button. But how can I go to Activity B without passing the "userid" to Activity B and keep it till it reached Activity E?

Comment: It's basic Java use of statics.  I put bare minimum code.  If you don't understand static members in Java, you should study that so you know what you're doing.

Comment: @DougStevenson but with noob developer use same pattern for even hugh object so

Comment: @androidnoobdev If you have a different better solution that's easy to explain here, I await your answer.